# OAuthRequestException received in App Engine Java Servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to access App Engine User profile in a Java Servlet as follows.

```
String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email profile";
OAuthService oathService = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
User user = oathService.getCurrentUser(scope);
```

Whenever the user data is accessed OAuthRequestException is thrown. The same code works in development mode but not in deployment mode.

I couldn't understand why the error was thrown. As far as I understood, the required permissions are available as stated in the online documentation (I guess!).

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: @saiyr As it happened only in deployment mode, I am not having the stack trace (Let me know if it is possible to take still). One thing what fishy is, a url is mapped to this servlet and a new tab will be oped for this servlet. As it is worked in development mode I didn't bothered much.

Comment: You should be able to see it or log it so that it appears in app logs.

Comment: @saiyr I am calling `ex.printStackTrace()` in the exception handler no stack traces seen in the Google Developer Console Logs Viewer. Log info messages are visible in the Logs Viewer however.

Comment: Better to use Logger directly and make sure logging.properties is configured properly.

Comment: @saiyr Managed to get stack trace https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6jpKO3DnIsZzktamZTV3l3bzQ It seems OAuth Paramater is giving an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was solved by calling `UserService` to get the current `User`. However the same is not working for development mode. May be somebody from Google App Engine team can explain!

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
user = userService.getCurrentUser();

if (user == null) {
    res.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OAuthRequestException is thrown when the request is not a valid OAuth request.
There are some examples at this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthServiceFactory), for instance:

```
   String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
   try {
    user = oauth.getCurrentUser(scope);
  } catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
    log("Impossible to authenticate the request from the image resizer, oauth request exception: "
        + e.getMessage());
    resp.setStatus(HttpStatusCodes.STATUS_CODE_UNAUTHORIZED);
    return;
  }
```